# How do I migrate my bot to an Azure Bot Service?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Recently, we have got a notification on https://dev.botframework.com/bots portal which states:

> With the launch of the new Azure Bot Service, we are migrating all bots to the new service by 3/31/2018

There's a migrate button against each bot (if you have many of them) which is supposed to do seamless migration for those whose Azure Subscription is associated with the same Microsoft Account as the one which was used to create a bot on http://dev.botframework.com/

My bots are associated with an X Microsoft Account and the Azure Subscription is with Y Microsoft Account.

Is there anyway to migrate? If yes then how.

Thanks

Comment: Documentation has one way to accomplish is to copy the source code from old to the new (Azure Bot Service). Is it the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the bot's owner/admin and migrate the bot by following these steps:

1. Log in to the [Bot Portal](https://dev.botframework) with the account used to create/register the bot.
2. Navigate to the "My bots" page
3. Select your bot
4. Navigate to the "Settings" page, and scroll down to the "Admin" section.
5. Add the email address connected to your Azure subscription to the "Owners" list, and click "Save changes" button.
6. Log out of Bot Portal
7. Log in to Bot Portal using your Azure subscription account you added in Step 5.
8. Navigate to the "Settings" page and remove your old email address from the "Admin > Owners" field.
9. Click "Save changes"
10. Navigate to the "My bots" page view and click the "migrate" button.

Note: Currently *only Bot Registrations are supported* for migration, and will be migrated to the Azure product called "Bot Channels Registration".
For more information on bot migration, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-migrate-bot

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The above part worked fine. 

Resource group was created successfully but there was an issue in migration which says 'Subscription is not registered (Code: SubscriptionNotRegistered).

Comment: Thanks for the update @ArafatTehsin - Can you contact your Azure tenant admin for assistance? If you are still having issues, open [a report here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new) and I will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for responding back again @nilsw, I have managed to resolve that. Actually, I had two owners of the bot and one of them had an expired subscription (my account X) -- thanks again.